# Uploadify, elaborating the file uploaded with a PHP script (server-side)

Tags: php, ajax, post, uploadify

I implemented Uploadify using the [official documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/implementing-uploadify/).

It works very fine, but I'd like elaborating the file uploaded with a PHP script (server-side) and return something to the page with the HTML form.
Any hits?

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Return something as in? It is not very clear when you say return something with the HTML form! could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: The PHP script is a log parser and returns part of file (text/xml) uploaded. 1) upload file with uploadify 2) parsing with PHP script (server-side) 3) return part of file to the javascript to show on site.

Answer (score 1):

as default uploadify sends the file to uploadify.php  here the uploaded file will be moved to your desired path. You can also add some extra functionality inside uploadify.php to edit the file... for example to shrink a uploaded picture or create thumbnails.

EDIT: how to receive something from uploadify.php

here is how I do it:

at first you need to output something from uploadify.php so add something like this to the bottom of php:

```
echo "Hello World";
```

now in your html code with javascript the response lands in "[onUploadSuccess](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/onuploadsuccess/)"
here is a javascript (jQuery) source of one of my projects.. you need to edit it / change the paths so it works for you..

```
$('#file_upload1').uploadify({
 'multi'    : false,
'formData'      : {'f' : dat},
    'swf'      : './js/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
    'uploader' : './uploadify.php',
 'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

after the upload you will get an alert which will show your output from uploadify.php - you can replace alert with other functions to embedd the response on your site. (See jQuery [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function for more info)

Comment: Yeah, wors fine, awesome! My PHP script returns HTML, so html function is perfect. I'd like add a div into the page (bottom to the form). Can I use html function to return the 'response" into the div? Have you an example? Thank you very much!

Comment: first add a div somewhere in your source where you want the code placed, for example <div id="thesource"></div> then in the above source code replace the alert function with $("#thesource").html(response);

Comment: Perfect! Thanks to everyone for the support!

Comment: Sometimes the script takes tens of seconds :( According to you, can I show a temporary banner "loading..." after the upload with uploadify (until the script returns something)? thank you very much